# Simple Grouped Barplot in R Studio

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I need help with a simple barplot in Rstudio, for my Statistics exam.

I have 4 SRS from which I estimated the mean and variance. Now I have a data frame with these errors:
[image]

I would like to create a barplot to show errors in all the simulation, both for mean and variance.
What I would obtain is something like this:
[image]

for example with mean errors in blue bars and variance errors in red bars; for each simulation.

**How can I do a plot like this?**

I found the plot in figure [here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) and of course I tried that code, but if I write this:

```
counts <- table(errors$MeanErr,errors$VarErr)
```

The result is:

```
counts

                      0.00580614250942646 0.00748139367270056 0.0110175973333068 0.242217731442113
  0.00565617345884917                   1                   0                  0                 0
  0.0235702639434603                    0                   1                  0                 0
  0.0720161457747945                    0                   0                  1                 0
  0.33541066066671                      0                   0                  0                 1
```

And

```
barplot(counts, names = c(10,100,1000,10000),legend = c("Mean","Variance"), beside=TRUE,xlab = "Number of Elements", ylab = "Error",col=c("Red","Darkblue"))
```

give this:
[image]
because, I think, it use the 1 and 0 value inside the table created.

I am at the beginning with R programming so thanks to everyone who will help me.

Comment: I think a scatter plot (`plot(MeanErr, VarErr)`) is the more natural way to display a relationship between two continuous variables.

Comment: +1 to @user20650's comment. Barplots are meant for count data. If you have a mean, use scatterplot.